# Is someone spying me through my webcam?

Tags: security, camera

I executed the following command in terminal and got the output:

Command:

> lsmod | grep uvcvideo

Output:

> uvcvideo               86016  0
>
> videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
>
> videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
>
> videobuf2_core         40960  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
>
> videodev              184320  3 videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
>
> media                  40960  2 videodev,uvcvideo

Does it mean my webcam is using by some application? I am running no application that uses my webcam and LED is not blinking.

Answer (score 1):

No.What you show is just kernel module dependency. This is nothing to do with spying.

[kernel-module-dependencies-on-Linux](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-check-kernel-module-dependencies-on-linux.html)

Comment: Please slightly elaborate...

Comment: @hanugm added a link you could refer to